# Knitr re double hash marks in output

Tags: r, knitr

I am reading ["Reproducible research with R and RStudio"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DJE0C9I). On page 29 the author writes that, using `knitr' this code:

```
Number <- 10
Number
```

should yield

```
## [1] 10
```

In the footnote he says that `knitr` automatically adds the double hashmarks.

Yet when I type:

```
library(knitr)
number <- 10
number
```

I get

```
[1] 10
```

just as if I had not installed `knitr`.

This is minor, but it might be important later in the book.

Comment: Can you describe exactly *how* you're using knitr in your workflow? It *looks* like you've just loaded the kintr library but haven't done any actual knitting yet.

Comment: In the book that's all it does. I am brand new to `knitr` so I just followed the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the code as below, and save it as `myfile.Rmd`, and click `Knit HTML` in RStudio.

````
```{r}
library(knitr)

number <- 10
number

```
````

Which in turn should create `myfile.html`, where you can see double hashes `##`:

[image]

Comment: If you are thinking of *Reproducible research*  read on more about R mark down syntax: http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/using_markdown